# Split Array Object response Using Dash Delimeted in PHP

Tags: php, implode

I have the response which is in the following array format I want that this data to be shown as

```
   ["123"]
```

1-2-3  Instead of combine number we can use implode if we have ['1','2','3']
but how to transfer one number like same way as implode returns for the following Number

```
$array = array('1', '2', '3');
$comma_separated = implode("-", $array);

echo $comma_separated;
```

How do we we add delemiter - and separate single object of array

Comment: I don't understand your question, but try looking at `str_split`

Comment: @RobbieAverill Simple is that I want 123 to be shown as 1-2-3

Comment: `str_split` + `implode`

Answer (score 0):

It is simple as this:

```
echo implode("-", str_split('123'));
```